Kotlin Ktor i have multipart form data request that i need to intercept and add some more parameters and resend it from inside the interceptor
Here is the request that i am sending as multipart setting files and plain text params.
suspend fun updateUserProfileInformation(
        docList: List<File>,
        type: String?,
        reason: String?,
        address: String?,
        requiredOtp: String?
    ): CommonOtpRes {
        val formData = formData {
            for (file in docList) {
                this.appendInput(
                    key = "documents",
                    headers = Headers.build {
                        append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentLength, file.length())
                        append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=${file.name}")
                    },
                    size = file.length()
                ) { buildPacket { writeFully(file.readBytes()) } }
            }
            append("type", type ?: "")
            append("reason", reason ?: "")
            if(!address.isNullOrEmpty())
                append("address", address)
            if(!requiredOtp.isNullOrEmpty())
                append("requiredOTPS", requiredOtp)
        }
        val response: HttpResponse = client.post("$VERSION/user-request/submit") {
            setBody(
                MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    formData
                )
            )
        }
        return response.body()
    }

Now what i need to do is once that gets called and response is received i need to check that whether some specific status code is received then i need to modify the request and resend it with updated parameters cloning the previous request body and adding additional type param to it. I am receiving the request.body type as the StreamRequestBody type now this class is internal and not directly accessible, so need to find a way to modify the content and resend it with new additional params.
Debug request body
What i have tried so far, original is the request from inside the interceptor once the response is received.
if(original.body is RequestBody && original.body?.isOneShot() == true) {
                val buffer = Buffer()
                original.body?.writeTo(buffer)
                val bodyString = buffer.readUtf8()
                Timber.e("Body Contents: $bodyString")
}

But here the content received is empty.
Previously with Retrofit this was how i had achieved the same but with ktor that is not possible somehow.
val builder: MultipartBody.Builder = MultipartBody.Builder()
                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                val requestBody = original.body as MultipartBody
                for (part in requestBody.parts) {
                    if (part.body.contentType() == "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaTypeOrNull() && part.headers?.get(
                            "Content-Disposition"
                        )?.contains("type") == true
                    ) {
                        builder.addFormDataPart("type", Gson().toJson(list))
                    } else {
                        builder.addPart(part)
                    }
                }
                val multipartReq = original.newBuilder()
                    .method(original.method, builder.build())
                    .build()
                return multipartReq


It's more difficult to do in Ktor because the multipart/form-data content has to be parsed in the Send hook. You can use the CIOMultipartDataBase internal class to parse the request body and then append the received parts to a FormPart list, which can be used to create the form data for the MultiPartFormDataContent class. The original request can be copied using the HttpRequestBuilder.takeFrom method. Here is an example:
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.api.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.client.request.forms.*
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.http.cio.*
import io.ktor.http.content.*
import io.ktor.util.*
import io.ktor.utils.io.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.DelicateCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import java.io.File
import kotlin.coroutines.EmptyCoroutineContext

val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(createClientPlugin("test") {
        on(Send) { request ->
            val call = proceed(request)

            val multipart = call.request.content

            if (multipart !is MultiPartFormDataContent) return@on call

            val readChannel = GlobalScope.writer {
                multipart.writeTo(channel)
            }.channel


            val multipartParser = CIOMultipartDataBase(EmptyCoroutineContext, readChannel, multipart.contentType.toString(), multipart.contentLength)

            // Copy parts
            val newParts = mutableListOf<FormPart<*>>()
            while (true) { 
                val part = multipartParser.readPart() ?: break

                if (part.contentType == ContentType.Application.Json && part.contentDisposition?.name == "type") {
                    newParts.add(FormPart("type", "{}"))
                } else {
                    when (part) {
                        is PartData.FormItem -> {
                            val name = part.name
                            if (name != null) {
                                newParts.add(FormPart(name, part.value, part.headers))
                            }
                        }

                        is PartData.FileItem -> {
                            val name = part.name
                            if (name != null) {
                                newParts.add(FormPart(name, InputProvider(block = part.provider), part.headers))
                            }
                        }

                        else -> error("")
                    }
                }
            }

            val newRequest = HttpRequestBuilder().takeFrom(request) // Create a copy of the request
            newRequest.setBody(
                MultiPartFormDataContent(
                    parts = formData(*newParts.toTypedArray()),
                    boundary = multipart.boundary
                )
            )

            proceed(newRequest)
        }
    })
}

val response = client.post("https://httpbin.org/post") {
    setBody(
        MultiPartFormDataContent(
            formData {
                append("description", "Ktor logo")
                append("type", "123", Headers.build {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "application/json")
                })
                append("image", File("archive.zip").readBytes(), Headers.build {
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/png")
                    append(HttpHeaders.ContentDisposition, "filename=\"ktor_logo.png\"")
                })
            },
            boundary = "WebAppBoundary"
        )
    )
}


fun httpClientAndroid() = HttpClient(okhttpEngine) {
install(ContentEncoding) {}
install(ContentNegotiation) {
json(
Json {
prettyPrint = true
isLenient = true
useAlternativeNames = true
ignoreUnknownKeys = true
}
)
}
thanks for the reply but i am using the OKHTTP engine instead of CIO. here is the interceptor part that i am having: https://imgur.com/a/pA7xhfk

The code will work with the OkHttp engine.

https://imgur.com/a/kgGWC88
i tried that but its showing error like the okhttp.request does not have the content object it has body but with that this above error is coming.

You have a problem with imports. I've updated my answer.
